# Printer HP problems in Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: printing

I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and printer HP LaserJet 1018. It doesn't print. Please advise.

Comment: I tried that. Terminal runs: <error: Package install command failed with error code 100
Would you like to retry installing the missing package(s) (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-pyqt5'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100
Would you like to retry installing the missing package(s) (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? 
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-pyqt5'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100>
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing foo2zjs driver.

foo2zjs is an open source printer driver for printers that use the Zenographics ZjStream wire protocol for their print data, such as the HP LaserJet 1020 or HP LaserJet Pro M12a/M12w or HP LaserJet Pro 1102 or HP LaserJet Pro 1018.

With foo2zjs, you can print to some HP and Minolta/QMS ZjStream
printers, such as these:

```
- Konica Minolta magicolor 2430 DL  B/W and color
- Minolta/QMS 2300 DL           B/W and color
- Minolta/QMS 2200 DL           B/W and color
- HP LaserJet P2035         B/W
- HP LaserJet M1319 MFP         B/W
- HP LaserJet Pro P1606dn       B/W
- HP LaserJet Pro P1566         B/W
- HP LaserJet Pro P1102         B/W
- HP LaserJet Pro CP1025nw      B/W and color
- HP LaserJet 1022          B/W
- HP LaserJet 1020          B/W
- HP LaserJet 1018          B/W
- HP LaserJet 1005          B/W
- HP LaserJet 1000          B/W
```

Download the driver and install it using following commands

```
git clone https://github.com/koenkooi/foo2zjs
```

Change the directory.

```
cd foo2zjs
```

Compile and install it.

```
make
```

Install driver, foomatic XML files and extra files.

```
sudo make install
```

Configure hotplug.

```
sudo make install-hotplug
```

Restart the spooler.

```
sudo make cups
```

Create printer entries for your spooler.

```
system-config-printer
```

Comment: Thank you. But my terminal answered: igor@igor-System-Product-Name:~$ wnloads     
wnloads: command not found
igor@igor-System-Product-Name:~$ $ wget -O foo2zjs.tar.gz http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/foo2zjs.tar.gz
$: command not found
igor@igor-System-Product-Name:~$

Comment: @Eugen: $ It is the user prompt as # it is the root. Commands are written without $. ~/Downloads is equal to /home/user/Downloads.

Answer (score 1):

you can download a new driver at this [Link](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip)
I use it for education and it helped me like alot! and by alot i mean like alot!

Answer (score 0):

I used these following steps. Installed hplip 3.23.3.run. When I tried printer set up it asked additional drivers. I opened hp.com web page. I clicked on hplip-3.23.3-plugin.run, it opened the page. I saved it using ctrl+ s in a directory. It saved as hplip-3.23.3-plugin.run. I ran hp-setup and set the path to this directory. Printer started working for me. Please try this.